Basic 1D advection equation in python using the finite difference method
Hi I am trying to code a simple advection equation in python using the finite difference upwind method. I have looked online to find a simple example of this but the codes I have found are a little more involved than what I expected to find. I have a simple code written in python where I have used a Gaussian initial condition.  The equation I am working with and code I have written are below:
Equation

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Mesh
Nx = 211 #Number of x grid points
Nt = 1000 #Number of t grid points

dx = 1/(Nx - 1) #Dividing dx into equal dx intervales
dt = 1e-7 #Time step

#Boundary conditions
x= np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, num=Nx)  
t= np.linspace(0.0, Nt*dt, num=Nt)

#Initializing array to zero
u=np.zeros((Nx, Nt)) #Initializing array to zero

#Velocity
c = 1 

#Gaussian initial condition
mu = 0.5
sigma = 0.1

for i in range(1,Nx-1):
    u[i,0] = np.exp(-(x[i]-mu)**2/(2*sigma**2)) / np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigma**2)


#Looping over all grid points excluding those at the boundary conditions
for j in range(0,Nt-1):   
    for i in range(1,Nx-1):
        
        u[i+1,j] = u[i,j] + c*(((1/x[i]) + (u[i+1,j] - (u[i,j])/dx)))*dt

plt.plot(x, u[:, 0])
plt.plot(x, u[:, 200])
plt.plot(x, u[:, 300])
plt.plot(x, u[:, 400])

I was expecting the plot to move to the left since the speed c>0 and wanted to see the plot at 4 different times beginning with the initial Gaussian starting point. But what I get doesn't make any sense. I also want to point out that when I comment out the for loop and do plt.plot(x,u[:,0] I see the initial Gaussian curve as expected when I type it again after uncommenting the for loop I get the plot shown below. I would greatly appreciate any help anyone can give me with this.
Output Plot

Your bracketing for the du/dx derivative is wrong. As it stands, dx is dividing into u[i,j] alone. To be honest, you are using far too many brackets.

@lastchance Thanks. I agree I am using too many brackets. I made the correction but I am still getting a plot that doesn't make sense. I'm hoping to get a bell curve at slightly further left positions for each of the 4 times I have in the code.I was trying to show the output I am getting on here but am having difficulty with that. This is my first question on stack overflow.

break the formula down into simple pieces. it is not necessary to squeeze everything onto one line.

You aren’t updating in time. The time index is j, so the LHS of your update step should be u[i,j+1], not u[i+1,j]

@lastchance Thanks again! the only thing is that my bell curve is staying in the same position and is not moving so when I run the code I only see one plot not 4 bell curves slightly to the left of the other as I am hoping for.

Your wave isn’t going to travel far at speed 1 in total time 0.0001. BTW, you don’t need to store all those time levels: just store two successive ones and plot as you go along.

@lastchance Got it! BTW what do you mean by storing at those time levels and to store at two successive ones and plot as I go along? I thought once the for loop is done all of the information I need is stored in the array u[i, j] so that I can pull what I need from it for the plots I want i.e. plt.plot(x, u[:, 1dt], plt.plot(x, u[:, 2dt] etc.

@lastchance I wanted to point out that I made my time step greater and now my Gaussian curve is now moving left as I want but the peak of the Gaussian is going up in height with each time step  as opposed to staying at the same height. Do you know why this might be?

@lastchance I made the first term on the RHS 0 and noticed that it is no longer increasing in height to the left but instead the height is slightly decreasing to the left now. The additional term c/r on the RHS seemed to be the reason why the peak was increasing as we move to the left but when I made it 0 I was expecting the plot to move to the left at the same height so I'm not sure why it is slightly decreasing.

@user24293678, if you include a term c/r then it is NOT a pure wave equation, so you would not expect the wave to keep its form. The wave equation in this instance is just du/dt=c.du/dx and will admit ANY solution of the form f(x+ct), including, but not limited to, gaussians. If you add a positive source term c/r then you would expect your solution to grow with time. In terms of timesteps, you simply have to keep the Courant number c.dt/dx less than 1 (so dt doesn't need to be as small as your have). When you make changes to your code PLEASE EDIT YOUR POST.

@lastchance Understood thank you again! When I did eliminate the source term the Gaussian no longer increased to the left but instead decreased very slightly to the left. I am assuming this is what is referred to in numerical analysis as numerical diffusion? Lastly when you say edit my post what exactly do you mean? I just want to make sure I follow what you requested.

Yes, it is numerical diffusion that is causing the (slight) loss in height. You can increase Nx to improve this. I have now written out a formal answer.

You can try this. Note, in particular:
I have temporarily switched off the source term (c/r) by multiplying it by 0. An accurate solution (increase Nx) will then advect unchanged.
I have corrected your du/dx term and the time level on the LHS.
With your Forward-Euler scheme you only need TWO time levels, plotting as you go along.
I have increased the number of x-nodes for greater accuracy. I have also made it consistent with dx.
You still need to think about your boundary conditions.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Time dependence
Nt = 1000          # number of timesteps
dt = 1e-3

# Space dependence
Nx = 901           # number of nodes
xmin, xmax = 0.1, 1.0
dx = ( xmax - xmin ) / (Nx - 1)
x= np.linspace(xmin, xmax, Nx)

# Equation variable (speed)
c = 1 

# Dependent variable with gaussian initial condition
mu = 0.5
sigma = 0.1
u = np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*sigma**2)) / np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigma**2)
plt.plot(x, u)

# Loop over all grid points excluding those at the boundary conditions (this IS a problem)
for j in range( 1, Nt + 1 ):
    uold = u.copy()
    for i in range(1, Nx - 1):
        u[i] = uold[i] + c * dt * ( uold[i+1] - uold[i] ) / dx    + 0 * c / x[i]
    if j % 100 == 0: plt.plot( x, u )

plt.show()

Output:


This was a great help! Thank you so much for your time explaining this to me. This is actually just a small part of a bigger project I am working on. I am going to post the next question shortly which involves a coupled system of diffusion advection equations.

How were you able to get that plot display on the page? When I try to display a plot it does a link that you have to click on which I don't want.

I think you need a minimum reputation in order to embed the plot directly in the page.

Thanks for this! In my original code I set my boundary conditions to zero. I thought that was indicated by the line x= np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, num=Nx) in my original code is it not? Also when I remove the multiplication by 0 I get a completely different curve than a bell curve is this to be expected?

If you remove the 0 multiplying the c/r then you will no longer have a wave equation. You will have a (large) source term and the profile is bound to evolve - especially for small values of x (=r, here). What you set as an array for x has no bearing on the boundary conditions for u (which really ought to be set at each timestep).

Right sorry about that my BC are zero at r_min and r_max. How can I properly include the boundary conditions?

You can just set those boundary conditions by u[0]=0 and u[-1]=0 at the start. If they were time-varying boundary conditions (e.g. zero gradient) then you could also update them at the end of each timestep (not needed here). At the moment you aren't having to do anything explicit because the initial gaussian was small at these points anyway and you aren't updating them.

u is a function or x and t so its a 2D array so wouldn't the boundary conditions be u[.1, 0] = 0 and u[1, Nt*dt] = 0? Also is the non Gaussian behavior when he remove the multiplication by 0 expected? I thought it would just cause the peak of the Gaussian to be higher each time as I was getting earlier but what I get is completely different.

@user24293678, I was referring to the 1-d array when discussing boundary conditions. It isn't appropriate to store 1000 time levels just to plot about five of them. The ends of the u array are then u[0] and u[-1], the latter being a Python shorthand for the end of the array. On your other point, if you bring back the c/r term then you are no longer solving a simple wave equation so the gaussian profile is bound to change. Since r (or x here) goes down to 0.1 then c/r can get as big as 10c. That will dwarf all other terms in the equation.

Ok got it. When I made the original changes in my original code that you suggested I got the bell curve moving to the left as I wanted but at slightly higher peaks each time which made sense because as you said including the source term the bell curve will change. However in this new code including the source term does not cause that. Instead the output plots are curves on top of each other on the lower left of the plot window. So I was trying to understand why that is?

There's honestly not much more to say. If you add the c/r term then it will cease to be a pure wave equation and as that term gets very large when r (or x, here) is small you will have a very large source term at low x. That's how your equation will behave: it's not a Python issue.

Ok, got it. Thank you so much for all of your time and help with this I greatly appreciate it!
